# Run two separate applications on same port with angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'd like to run two seperate applications on the same port, one for the 'customers' and the other for the 'administators'. In angular cli you can add multiple apps in the `.angular-cli.json` but you can't run them at the same time. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new module that includes both of apps.
1. Add a new app to .angular-cli.json:

```
"apps": [
{
  "name": "all",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main-all.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}, .......
```

2. Create main-all.ts file such as you do for other apps. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps

3. Create a common module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    AppModule1,
    AppModule2
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent1, AppComponent2]
})
export class AppModuleAll {}
```